# Changing write policy from "write through" to "write back" on NVME

Tags: mount, ssd

I am running extremely write-intensive processes on an enterprise class NVME SSD that does not have an operating system.  My concern for data integrity for what I'm running is literally zero - if I were to lose power, all the data on the drive would be useless anyway.  Even if the filesystem were corrupted by power loss, I wouldn't even bother to fsck, I would just delete and recreate the partition.  What I need is best performance and to minimize writes on the drive.

I have already set the following mount options on the drive:  discard,noatime,nodiratime,barrier=0.  I also disabled journaling.  These all gave me worthwhile performance gains.

My problem is that when I do:

```
sudo cat /sys/block/myNVMEdevice/queue/write_cache
```

...I still get a response of "write through".  Not surprising that would be the default setting on an enterprise disk.  I want to make this "write back" as I believe the current setting is likely incurring unnecessary overhead that accomplishes nothing due to my other settings.  If it were a normal disk, I would use:

```
hparm -W1 /dev/nvmen0
```

...but that doesn't seem to work on NVME disks ("HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device").  I did install nvme-cli, which was useful as I couldn't get any SMART information from the drives previously, but still not seeing a way to change the write policy.

I have scoured the internet for hours and cannot find an answer.  Please someone help!  Thanks in advance for any that may come.

Answer (score 1):

Writeback policy on NVMe devices if controlled via feature 6

```
nvme set-feature -f 6 -v 1 /dev/nvme0n1
```

[discussion on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/voidlinux/comments/hl2b9f/comment/g34aqtk/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

But most enterprise NVMe devices have power loss protection (PLP)
More info from [Kingston](https://www.kingston.com/en/solutions/servers-data-centers/ssd-power-loss-protection), [Micron](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/white-paper/ssd_power_loss_protection_white_paper_lo.pdf), [Samsung](https://image-us.samsung.com/SamsungUS/b2b/resource/2016/07/08/b2b_resource_WHP-SSD-POWERLOSSPROTECTION-r1-JUL16J.pdf)

You should do nothing to enable writeback caching on NVMe device with PLP.
Standard says:

> 5.21.1.6 Volatile Write Cache (Feature Identifier 06h), (Optional)
> This Feature controls the volatile write cache, if present, on the controller. If a volatile write cache is present (refer to the VWC field in Figure 247), then this feature shall be supported. The attributes are indicated in Command Dword 11.
> **Note: If the controller is able to guarantee that data present in a write cache is written to non-volatile media on loss of power, then that write cache is considered non-volatile and this feature does not apply to that write cache.**